# Ground pour under ESP8266 12-E

Tags: esp8266, signal-integrity, ground-plane, copper-pour

I want to pour ground under a ESP8266 12-E just for thermal reasons but I don't know if this can affect it somehow or if it's safe to do. The PCB is all under 5V, it's only 2 layers and it would have some signal traces, all on top. I have noted that with ground pour I get some more free space because I don't need GND traces (and would have several of them).

So I have three questions:

1) Does the ground pour affect ESP12-E?

2) Is it safe to have a ground pour with signal traces on it?

3) If it's safe to do 1 and 2, I should pour ground on bottom too, right?

Comment: There won't be a safety issue. However, since the module is a WiFi device, having a "ground-plane" under it may significantly affect it's performance, especially in that direction. Further, an unconnected "ground-pour" will likely cause some grief to other signals on the board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* pour ground under the antenna area, leave both layers free from pours and traces in the area immediately below the antenna; you do not want bits of copper coupling to the antenna. A ground pour under the non-antenna portion of the ESP-12E is fine, although I would avoid pouring on the top layer, as there is a (very slight) possibility of a short if both masks (on your board and the ESP) were to become damaged in the same spot and make contact. However, this chance is very slight, and if you want to pour under the ESP on top, it's probably fine.

> 1) Does the ground pour affect ESP12-E?

Yes, when it's under the antenna.

> 2) Is it safe to have ground pour with signal traces on it?

Sure, most ground pours have traces in them.

> 3) If it's safe to do 1 and 2, I should pour ground on bottom too, right?

Yes, just not under the antenna.

You should also not route traces under the antenna, and again, if it were me, I wouldn't route traces on the top directly under the device, as they would be very close to the ESP's traces (only separated by two layers of soldermask) and could be interfered with.